# Ax 2012 Error executing code: Wrong argument types in variable assignment when confirming PO

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

i have completed an in place upgrade from ax 2012 rtm to ax 2012 r2

but currently i am having the below exception when trying to Confirm a purchase order

Error executing code: Wrong argument types in variable assignment.

Stack trace

```
(S)\Classes\FormLetterContract\unpack - line 8

(S)\Classes\PurchFormLetterContract\unpack - line 13

(S)\Classes\SysOperationDataContractInfo\unpackDataContractObject - line 21

(S)\Classes\SysOperationController\unpackDataContractInfoObjects - line 34

(S)\Classes\SysOperationController\unpack - line 70

(S)\Classes\SysOperationServiceController\unpack - line 15

(S)\Classes\PurchFormLetter\unpack - line 10

(S)\Classes\PurchFormLetter_PurchOrder\unpack - line 73

(S)\Classes\xSysLastValue\getLast - line 29

(S)\Classes\SysOperationController\loadFromSysLastValue - line 29

(S)\Classes\SysOperationController\getDataContractInfoObjects - line 10

(S)\Classes\SysOperationController\getDataContractInfoObject - line 17

(S)\Classes\SysOperationController\getDataContractObject - line 18

(S)\Classes\FormLetterServiceController\init - line 3

(S)\Classes\PurchFormLetter_PurchOrder\init - line 3

(S)\Classes\PurchFormLetter_PurchOrder\newPurchOrder - line 7

(S)\Classes\PurchFormLetter\construct - line 11

(S)\Classes\PurchFormLetter\mainOnServer - line 46

(C)\Classes\PurchFormLetter\main - line 50

(C)\Classes\FormFunctionButtonControl\Clicked
```

i tried to debug it and reached to this point  where exception occurs on     [version, #ParmListFormLetter] = _packedClass; in the FormLetterContract

i tried to clear xppil, do a full compile and CIL generation and sync dictionary but the error still appear i also checked for customization in the classes in the stack trace but all of them are sys layer and free of any customization

```
public boolean  unpack(container  _packedClass)
{
    Integer  version = conPeek(_packedClass,1);

    switch (version)
    {
        case #CurrentVersion:
            [version, #ParmListFormLetter] = _packedClass;
            break;
        default :
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

could any one advice about this 
your help is most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code you presented, and without any knowledge of these classes' changes from 2012 RTM, I'd do the following:

1. Make sure the parm list that is specified in the #ParmListFormLetter macro (found in the FormLetterContract class declaration) matches the parm list coming in through _packedClass. If they are different, you will need to change the version number specified in the CurrentVersion macro. Then write a custom handler for the differences in the default case of the switch in your code.
2. Try compiling FormLetterContract forward. Right click on the class node from the AOT, and go to Add-Ins > compile forward. This will resolve any inheritance-related type issues. The only time I have experienced the error you described, compile-forward was all I had to do to resolve it.